# errorCode : MINIMUM_SERVER when access obtainAccessToken in IBM MFP8

Tags: ionic2, ibm-mobilefirst, mfp

I'm getting failure when trying to call

```
 WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken()
```

Using Ionic 2 and MFP 8

**This is the message**

> ============== {"status":-1,"responseText":"","errorMsg":"This version of the MobileFirst client SDK requires a minimal server version
>   greater than IFIX
>   8.0.0.0-IF201701250919","errorCode":"MINIMUM_SERVER"}

Our installation team installed the latest iFix pack also.

I'm attaching the code snippet also.

## *app.component.ts*

```
WL.Client.pinTrustedCertificatePublicKey('mycert.cer').then(() => {
console.log('--------SSL Pin Success-------------');
WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken().then((accessToken) => {
console.log('--------accessToken Success-------------', accessToken);
}, (response) => {
console.log('--------accessToken Failure-------------', response);
let usrname ="roney";
let passwrd = "roney@123";
let modalc = this.modal.create("UserLoginChallengeHandler",{"username":usrname,"password":passwrd});
modalc.present();
modalc.onDidDismiss((data)=>{
//further to proceed goes here
this.statusBar.styleDefault();
this.splashScreen.hide();
this.fcmInformation();
}); 
}); 
}).fail((error) => {
console.log('--------SSL Pin failed-------------', error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This means, your server is still running an iFix level that is older than the client. It is possible the server is still not updated - may be the update wasn't proper or complete. Server side log ( tracing) will tell exactly what versions of server side components are running. 
Another option is to verify the network capture - this will give more details on the server side message and version.